# Why fiber bundles are locally products

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, tangent-bundle, co-tangent-space

I'm a first year graduate student in math and I'm currently studying fiber bundles. The definition is clear and I understand how it generalize concepts as (co)tangent bundles or vector bundles. What for me is unclear is why we are interested in spaces which are locally product of spaces. What is in general its usefulness? Thanks.

Comment: In the title you ask why fiber bundles are locally products. In the body you ask why such local products are interesting. You should clarify what you want to ask.

Comment: To address the question in the body, an arbitrary mapping $f:X \to Y$ may be viewed as a section of the (trivial) product $X \times Y$ via $x \mapsto\bigl(x, f(x)\bigr)$. Fiber bundles generalize this.